# How to create unit-testing for $http promise in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a service with a function to use $http with promise. And i want create a unit-testing with jasmine.

```
account.service('AccountService', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    this.getServerDataForUrl = function (url) {
         var def = $q.defer();
         $http.get(url)
              .success(function (data) {
                   if (data) {
                      def.resolve(data);
                   } else {
                      def.reject();
                   }
               })
               .error(function (error) {
                   if (data) {
                      def.resolve(data);
                   } else {
                      def.resolve();
                   }
                });
         return def.promise;
    };
}]);
```

**UPDATE:** Change something code when callback.
I've search about it but it not give me exactly function like this. Anyone give me some example to create unit-testing about it. I think this function is simple. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that can be tested here is whether a request was made to the specific url. There are numerous example of testing http service online.

Comment: Actually what you are doing in your code is redundant. $http itself returns a promise. Why do you need to have such code?

Comment: [The forgotten promise anti-pattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/#the_forgotten_promise)

Comment: Hi @Chandermani. It's not my code. My mission is write unit-testing for it :)

Answer (score 3):

You should really just

```
return $http.get(url);
```

There's no point in wrapping a promise in a deferred object.

This is the only testable thing I can think of

```
describe('AccountService test', function() {
    var $http;

    beforeEach(module('accountModule', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$http', $http = jasmine.createSpyObj('$http', ['get']));

        // if you aren't going to change the code to not wrap
        // the $http promise, add this

        var httpPromise = {
            success: function(cb) {
                cb('success');
                return httpPromise;
            },
            error: function(cb) {
                cb('error');
                return httpPromise;
            }
        };

        $http.get.and.returnValue(httpPromise);
    }));

    it('proxies through to $http.get', inject(AccountService) {
        AccountService.getServerDataForUrl('url');
        expect($http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('url');
    }));
});
```

Comment: I run your code. But it get message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined". What can i do with your code now?

Comment: @PhamMinhTan I assumed you'd update the code to not wrap the `$http` promise in a deferred object. I've updated my answer

Comment: Great! Your code is run properly.Thank you. Can you give me some tutorial and example to write unit-testing. Because, i want to write it. Anyway. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

in spec create an variable which holds the reference of your AccountService instance and use angular inject function to get it instantiated.

now you can use jasmine spys for testing functions or use marchers to test service public members.

```
    var AccountSvs = undefined;
    beforeEach(inject(function (AccountService) {
    AccountSvs = AccountService;
    }));

    it('..', function(){
      expect(AccountSvs.getServerDataForUrl).toBeDefined();
AccountSvs.getServerDataForUrl().then(/*success callback*/function(){}, /*error callback*/function(){}, /*notify callback*/function(){});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

its not a big deal to handle promise in unit testing since its async you need to the following.

```
describe('AccountService',function(){
 var service = null;
    beforeEach(inject(function (AccountService) {
    service = AccountService;
    }));

    it('checkService here', function(done){
         expect(service .getServerDataForUrl).toBeDefined();
        service .getServerDataForUrl().then(function(resp){
         expect(resp.data).not.ToBeNull();   
          done();

     });
});
```

`resp.data`  will contain your actual data returned from service.